# Google Closure Compiler can't read file

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I upgraded the Google Closure Compiler to v20171112, and suddenly one of my JavaScript files generated this message:

```
ERROR - Cannot read file myfile.js: {1}
```

with no other explanation.

Answer (score 0):

By gradually chopping bits out of the file, I found that the problem was a £ sign in a comment. I removed it and the compiler worked fine again.